# I'm currently trying to put a python environment in a nodered, but i get the error "pyfile not exist"

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm currently trying to put a python environment in a nodered, but when I implement it according to this url (https://flows.nodered.org/flow/778859ca2503db35ff0e12341508efef) I get the error "pyfile not exist" In the embedded_file_node setting, I selected String for "Output", the current directory is / home / vcap / app, and set "Name" to create_env.sh.

I'm a complete beginner and have self-taught so far, but I asked because there was no other information about this detail anywhere else.
I would appreciate any help.

The template code is as follows.

Contents of template (below)

```
cd /data
ls -l
python3 --version
#python3 -m venv envtest
#source envtest/bin/activate
ls -l
which python3
```

Comment: You need to include a LOT more information in your questions. Assuming you are running this on IBM Cloud you should not be trying to use the local file system as it is not persisted when the environment chooses to restart your app. Also I doubt there is a `/data` directory for that script to run in

Comment: Currently, i am unable to disclose debug information due to another problem. Please see here for details. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66085523/nothing-is-displayed-in-the-debug-node-in-nodered)

Comment: I set the template syntax to none (because I can't do it anywhere else), and I'm only trying the "ls -l" command in the template.
However, I am getting the error "File format error" in embedded_file_node.
The question is how can I create a file from nodered on ibm cloud?

Is there a suitable node other than embedded_file_node?

Comment: You should not be using any file nodes on IBM Clould. The default nodes are removed for a reason.